# How to display a welcome window like in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

For example when you start Xcode, a welcome window appears. You select recent project and Xcode opens a new window with your project and closes the welcome window. After you close the project window, only main menu is visible. And if you click on Xcode icon in the dock, welcome window will appear again.

So the question is how to make my welcome window open if a user clicks on the dock icon?

Comment: Are you creating a document-based application?

Comment: No. I devided my app into 2 parts. And welcome window is sort of glue between those parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using a custom application delegate. When the application is opened from the finder or dock, if it has no windows it will call `applicationOpenUntitledFile:` on it's delegate (as long as you don't override other methods to prevent it). You can use that method to display a welcome window. I would also suggest creating a custom window controller for your window to handle all document actions (i.e. open and new) so that you can hide the window if the user creates a document using the menu bar. See the [NSApplicationDelegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Wow! Thanks. You helped me to figure out a bunch of interesting moments.

Comment: I am returning `false` from `-applicationOpenUntitledFile:`, but the new document still shows. Also, it is not clear from the docs how it plays (and if I should override) `applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:`.

Comment: The funny thing is, you have to return `true` now to suppress opening the new untitled document. Yet, Apple documentation and tradition state otherwise.